# Labelling arrows drawn to paths in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to draw a (commutative) diagram using `tikz-cd`. The package manual, in section 3.2, describes how to use `to path` for fine-grained control of the shapes of arrows, but says little on how to then add labels to these arrows.

I currently have the following diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & K^n \arrow[r, "L^A_B(F)"] \arrow[dd, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztostart.west) -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztotarget.west) -- (\tikztotarget.west)}] & K^m \arrow[dd, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([xshift=10ex, "L^B_D"]\tikztostart.east) -- ([xshift=10ex]\tikztotarget.east) -- (\tikztotarget.east)}] & \\
        V \arrow[rrr, "F"] \arrow[ru, "C_A"] \arrow[rd, "C_C"'] & & & W \arrow[lu, "C_B"'] \arrow[ld, "C_D"] \\
        & K^n \arrow[r, "L^C_D(F)"] & K^m &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]
I'd like to add the Labels `L^A_C`and `L^B_D` to the outer ,,bendy`` arrows, but I'm drawing a blank as to how. The obvious, straightforward way (adding labels to the path) does not produce anything, while adding a phantom arrow to create a coordinate for where the label would then be placed, as in the `tikz-cd` documentation, produces an error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \arrow[dd, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z} && K^n \arrow[r, "L^A_B(F)"] \arrow[dd, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztostart.west) -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztotarget.west) -- (\tikztotarget.west)}] & K^m \arrow[dd, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([xshift=10ex, "L^B_D"]\tikztostart.east) -- ([xshift=10ex]\tikztotarget.east) -- (\tikztotarget.east)}] & \\
        &V \arrow[rrr, "F"] \arrow[ru, "C_A"] \arrow[rd, "C_C"'] & & & W \arrow[lu, "C_B"'] \arrow[ld, "C_D"] \\
        && K^n \arrow[r, "L^C_D(F)"] & K^m &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

yields

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-3-1' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
...
l.6 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
```

and several more errors in the same vein.

Comment: You can add `node[left]{\scriptsize$L_A^C$}` to the second connector `--`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a node at the second segment of the path.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  & K^n 
  \arrow[r, "L^A_B(F)"] 
  \arrow[dd, rounded corners, 
    to path={ 
      -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztostart.west) 
      --node[left]{\scriptsize$L_C^A$} ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztotarget.west) 
      -- (\tikztotarget.west)}
        ]
  & K^m
  \arrow[dd, rounded corners, 
    to path={ 
      -- ([xshift=10ex, "L^B_D"]\tikztostart.east) 
      --node[right]{\scriptsize$L_D^B$} ([xshift=10ex]\tikztotarget.east)   
      -- (\tikztotarget.east)}] 
  & \\
  V 
  \arrow[rrr, "F"] 
  \arrow[ru, "C_A"] 
  \arrow[rd, "C_C"'] 
  & & & W 
  \arrow[lu, "C_B"'] 
  \arrow[ld, "C_D"] \\
  & K^n 
  \arrow[r, "L^C_D(F)"] 
  & K^m &
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Simple, effective, and should have been obvious. Thank you!

Comment: @chsk, you are welcome

Comment: Excuse for my previous bad answer.

Answer (score 5):

On encouragement by "Schrodinger's cat" I made a general key to do this. I called it "relay arrow" but if anyone has a better name, let me know. It works by saying e.g., `\ar[ur, relay arrow=10pt]`.

This is strictly speaking not relevant to the question asked, but my hope is it might be useful to someone.

Here's the effect:
[image]

Code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
    relay arrow/.default = 10pt,
    relay arrow/.style = {
        rounded corners,
        to path = {
            \pgfextra{
                \def\sourcecoordinate{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}
                \def\targetcoordinate{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztotarget}{center}}
                \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\sourcecoordinate}{\targetcoordinate}
                \edef\tempangle{\pgfmathresult}
                \pgftransformrotate{\tempangle}
                \pgfmathifthenelse{#1>0}{\tempangle+90}{\tempangle-90}
                \pgfcoordinate{tempcoord}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{\pgfmathresult}}
            }
            (tempcoord)
            -- ([yshift=#1]tempcoord)
            -- ([yshift=#1]tempcoord-|\tikztotarget.center)\tikztonodes
            --(\tikztotarget)
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
     & B\\
    A \urar[relay arrow,"1"]\urar["2"]\urar[relay arrow=-25pt,"3"']&
    \end{tikzcd}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        && K^n \arrow[r, "L^A_B(F)"]
        \arrow[dd, "L_A^C"', relay arrow=-10ex]
        & K^m
        \arrow[dd,"L_D^B", relay arrow=10ex] &
        \\
        &V \arrow[rrr, "F"] \arrow[ru, "C_A"] \arrow[rd, "C_C"'] & & & W \arrow[lu, "C_B"'] \arrow[ld, "C_D"] \\
        && K^n \arrow[r, "L^C_D(F)"] & K^m &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `\tikztonodes` in `to path` and then use quotes to specify the labels. The labels specified using the quotes get stored into `\tikztonodes`. This is much more useful if you want to use the same "tikz to path" to draw multiple paths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        && K^n \arrow[r, "L^A_B(F)"] 
        \arrow[dd, rounded corners, "L_A^C"', 
            to path={ 
                 -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztostart.west) 
                 -- ([xshift=-10ex]\tikztotarget.west)\tikztonodes % added \tikztonodes here
                 -- (\tikztotarget.west)
        }] 
        & K^m 
        \arrow[dd,"L_D^B", rounded corners, 
            to path={ 
                 -- ([xshift=10ex]\tikztostart.east) 
                 -- ([xshift=10ex]\tikztotarget.east)\tikztonodes 
                 -- (\tikztotarget.east)
        }] &
        \\
        &V \arrow[rrr, "F"] \arrow[ru, "C_A"] \arrow[rd, "C_C"'] & & & W \arrow[lu, "C_B"'] \arrow[ld, "C_D"] \\
        && K^n \arrow[r, "L^C_D(F)"] & K^m &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `to path={ 
                 -- ([xshift=10ex]\tikztostart.east) 
                 -- ([xshift=10ex]\tikztostart.east|-\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes 
                 -- (\tikztotarget.east)
        }`? In this very example it works fine, but in general the nodes won't be of equal width, and with your (as well as all others') construction the second segment may end up being not vertical.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sounds good. It seems to me that the question was just how to add a label to a custom `to path` not what the best `to path` to use is. With your construction you could add an extra distance option and make this into a general use key.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I wrote the code for this, posted in a separate answer. It took some energy to get right, but I think the result looks pretty good. =)

Answer (score 4):

This uses plain TikZ. `pos=.25` is due to operation `++` that updated the new position for calculations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2.5} \def\b{1.3}
\path
(0,0) node[above]{$F$}
(\a,0) node (W) {$W$}
(-\a,0) node (V) {$V$}
(.4*\a,\b) node (Kmt) {$K^m$}
(-.4*\a,\b) node (Knt) {$K^n$}
(.4*\a,-\b) node (Kmb) {$K^m$}
(-.4*\a,-\b) node (Knb) {$K^n$};
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway,scale=.7}]
\draw[->] (V)--(W);
\draw[->] (Knt)--(Kmt) node[above]{$L_B^A(F)$}; 
\draw[->] (Knb)--(Kmb) node[below]{$L_D^C(F)$};
\draw[->] (V)--(Knt) node[above left]{$C_A$};
\draw[->] (W)--(Kmt) node[above right]{$C_B$};
\draw[->] (V)--(Knb) node[below left]{$C_C$};
\draw[->] (W)--(Kmb) node[below right]{$C_D$};
\draw[->,rounded corners] (Kmt)--++(0:.8*\a)|-(Kmb) node[pos=.25,right]{$L_D^B(F)$};
\draw[->,rounded corners] (Knt)--++(180:.8*\a)|-(Knb) node[pos=.25,left]{$L_A^C(F)$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```